# Why my linebreak checker is not giving the expected result?

Tags: java

I have created a project using Java to simulate a Library, I have a method named "Arrumbadas" that return those publishings which have never been lend separated by a linefeed and a test that only checks if each line of this result ("Arrumbadas" method) has a linefeed at the end.

I have implemented "Arrumbadas" method as follow:

```
(Omitted code)
     result = new StringBuilder();
      for(omitted code){
       if(omitted code){
         result.append(publishing).append(\n)
        }
       }
      return result.toString()
```

I have implemented the test as follow:

```
  public static boolean hasLineFeed(String t){
        Scanner text = new Scanner(t);
        while(text.hasNextLine()){
            String line = text.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            if(!line.endsWith("\n") && !line.isEmpty()){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Given this certain text:

```
"9780547928227","The Hobbit","J.R.R. Tolkien","2","0","High fantasy"
"9780316769174","The Catcher in the Rye","J.R.R. Tolkien","3","0","Coming-of-age fiction"
"9780143124672","Moby-Dick","J.R.R. Tolkien","1","0","Adventure fiction"
```

The output of the test is:

```
"9780547928227","The Hobbit","J.R.R. Tolkien","2","0","High fantasy"
Has linefeed: false
```

Figure out that .hasNextLine() doesnt include the delimiter, neither does .split() that I had used it before. Is there a way to read the text by lines without removing the delimiters?

Comment: Don't like to your code, include it in your question. Check the formatting help for how (basically, put three backticks (The '`' character) on a line, paste your code, another line with 3 backticks.

Comment: Yes, this isn't a "please check the code in the link" help site, and in fact isn't even a help site per se, but rather a question and answer site, where we hope to have high quality questions and answers that are helpful to all -- to the original poster as well as to future visitors who come to the site for solutions to similar problems. Mainly for this reason, it is best to have all code and all important resources readily visible in your question as text (for code, as code-formatted text). Please check out the [ask] and [tour] link for the details as well as the [help] link.

Comment: split does not include the delimiter in the resulting array so there will never be a newline in it.

Comment: I think you should post a [mcve]. Are you saying that you are not getting your expected result?

Comment: Edited giving a minimal reproducible example. Yes, the result of the test is not the expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Scanner` class (Java 17 at least) uses the following regex to match a line separator:

```
\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]
```

As you can see, this will match a CR, an LF or a CR followed by a LF<sup>1</sup>. After matching,  line separator at the end of the line is then removed, as per the javadoc.  That means that `readLine()` will NEVER return a line that ends with an LF (i.e. `'\n'`) or a CR (i.e. `'\r'`).

> Is there a way to read the text by lines without removing the delimiters?

Not using `Scanner.nextLine()` or `BufferedReader.readLine()`.  If you really need to preserve the line separator, the simplest way is to use a `for` loop to read a characters from `BufferedReader`, recognize line separators, and assemble lines yourself.  You can then include the line separators in the line strings, or put them into a different variable.

HOWEVER ... it is not obvious to me why you need to preserve the line separators if you are simply reading a CSV file.  If I was doing this, I would use `BufferedReader.readLine` to read each line, and then use a `Scanner` or `String.split` or something more sophisticated to deal with the commas and quotes.

Or ... find and use a 3rd party CSV parser library and save the effort of implementing the code yourself.

---

<sup>1 - ... and some other obscure codes that you've probably never heard of.</sup>